# Can I get the tweet object from a reply tweet I posted with Twitter API?

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am creating an app that will display a users tweets. Using the twitter API I have managed to get the access token and request a list of recent tweets:

```
[[[BTwitterManager sharedManager] getTwitterAPI] getUserTimelineWithScreenName:[[BTwitterManager sharedManager] getCurrentScreenName] count:20 successBlock:^(NSArray * statuses) {

}
errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}];
```

This gets me an array of recent tweets.

My problem arises when I want to deal with a reply to a tweet. Ideally I would be able to show both the original tweet and also the reply that I posted.

If we look at the tweet object (I have taken out a lot of the irrelevant stuff to save space):

```
"created_at" = "Wed May 21 22:26:17 +0000 2014";

entities =     {

    "user_mentions" = ({

            id = 15439395;

            "id_str" = 15439395;

            name = "Stephen Fry";

            "screen_name" = stephenfry;

        } ); };

id = 469242805592674305;

"id_str" = 469242805592674305;

"in_reply_to_screen_name" = stephenfry;

"in_reply_to_status_id" = 469239740999696384;

"in_reply_to_status_id_str" = 469239740999696384;

"in_reply_to_user_id" = 15439395;

"in_reply_to_user_id_str" = 15439395;

text = "@stephenfry blah blah blah twitter";

user =     {

    "created_at" = "Mon Aug 22 16:10:07 +0000 2011";

    id = 360047219;

    "id_str" = 360047219;

    name = "Wee Splodge";

    notifications = 0;

    "screen_name" = WeeSplodge;

    "statuses_count" = 79;

};
```

We have my tweet reply but not the original post. We do though have status id of this.

Is there any way to use the information available to get the original tweet which was replied to?

What would be perfect would be a function that allows you to pull up a tweet using an id and a username but currently I can't find anything helpful.